# Using a Partial, How to Create a Multi Controller ROOT ROUTE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, resources, root

How can we make the root route provide: habits, valuations, goals, quantifieds (not just valuations as it currently is)?

And to make matters more difficult how can we only show `@unaccomplished_goals` and not `@accomplished_goals` when including the goals controller in the root route?

The root route would show this in 1 view:

```
Habits Table
Valuations Table
Unaccomplished Goals Table
Quantifieds Table
```

I was told I need to use a partial to share code across the application. How can we do this so that the root route could lead to something like "home"?

**routes**

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :habits

  resources :goals

  resources :valuations

  resources :quantifieds
  
  resources :results

  devise_for :users
  root 'valuations#index'
  get "about" => "pages#about"
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'valuations#index', as: :tag

end
```

**controllers**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
   @habits = current_user.habits
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @habit = current_user.habits.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @habit = current_user.habits.build(habit_params)
    if @habit.save
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @habit.update(habit_params)
      redirect_to @habit, notice: 'Habit was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @habit.destroy
    redirect_to habits_url
  end

  private
    def set_habit
      @habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @habit = current_user.habits.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to habits_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this habit" if @habit.nil?
    end

    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :date_started, :trigger, :action, :target, :positive, :negative, :committed => [])
    end
end

class ValuationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_valuation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @valuations = Valuation.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @valuations = Valuation.order('RANDOM()')
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @valuation = current_user.valuations.build(valuation_params)
    if @valuation.save
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @valuation.update(valuation_params)
      redirect_to @valuation, notice: 'Value was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @valuation.destroy
    redirect_to valuations_url
  end

  private
    def set_valuation
      @valuation = Valuation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @valuation = current_user.valuations.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to valuations_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this valuation" if @valuation.nil?
    end

    def valuation_params
      params.require(:valuation).permit(:name, :tag_list)
    end
end
                                                  
class GoalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_goal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @goals = Goal.all.order("deadline")
   @accomplished_goals = current_user.goals.accomplished
   @unaccomplished_goals = current_user.goals.unaccomplished
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @goal = current_user.goals.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.build(goal_params)
    if @goal.save
      redirect_to goals_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @goal.update(goal_params)
      redirect_to goals_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @goal.destroy
    redirect_to goals_url
  end

  private
    def set_goal
      @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @goal = current_user.goals.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to goals_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @goal.nil?
    end

    def goal_params
      params.require(:goal).permit(:name, :deadline, :accomplished)
    end
end

class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @quantifieds = Quantified.joins(:results).all
   @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
   @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build 
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :name, :metric, :result, :date, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

If we need to work with other files:
**Github:** https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday
Or I could add them here.

Thanks for your expertise =]

Comment: What is your expectation here?  That all 5 of those controllers render to 1 view at your root?

Comment: Yes with the exception of `accomplished goals`

Comment: You're not going to get that behavior as you described but you can use partials to help you share code across your application.

Comment: The root route is _the root route_.  It controls what happens when a browser requests the root URL, `/`. Only one thing can happen the root route is requested (or at least only one controller can be routed too, that controller can decide to do different things based on something other than the root). What are you actually trying to accomplish, in terms of mapping from URLs to controllers?

Comment: Hi @jrochkind I realize my means is inappropriate toward solving the ends of this question. I readjusted the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Anthony I readjusted the question. I thought Rails would make this simpler than it's turning out to be.